# Nashorn and Scala future to JS Promise conversion

Tags: javascript, java, scala, nashorn

I have a server side implemented in `Scala` and `React/Flux` based front end. My services return `Futures` and they are handled within Scalatra's `AsyncResult` for JSON responses.

For isomorphic/server side rendering setup I did not want to change services to be blocking so I started with Scala Future-> `java.util.function.Function` conversion [shown here](http://blog.eigengo.com/2014/05/30/scala-futures-and-jdk-1-8-scripting/).

But the dispatcher in Flux would like to have JS Promise. So far I found only rather complicated sounding way around this  [Slides 68-81](http://www.slideshare.net/SpringCentral/serverside-javascript-with-nashorn-and-spring)

Is there any recommended way to deal with this Scala Future -> JS Promise conversion?

Comment: Don't have details, but the easiest options is to make  the promise on JS side from functions. For example the q promise library has: 
q.promise(function(resolve, reject) { ...})

Comment: Have you looked at how Scala.js handles and converts Scala Futures to JS promises?

Comment: I think the Play Framework has a library for this. play.lib.F.Promise has a method 'wrap' that creates a Promise wrapped in a Future, and 'wrapped' which returns the Promise wrapped in a Future.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to answer the Scala Future to JS Promise part of the question.
As you haven't provided an example. I will provide one here with the conversion.
If we say that we have a Future implemented in Scala this way:

```
val f: Future = Future {
  session.getX()
}

f onComplete {
  case Success(data) => println(data)
  case Failure(t) => println(t.getMessage)
}
```

then the corresponding code in JavaScript/ES6 could look like this:

```
var f = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
   session.getX();
});

f.then((data) => {   
  console.log(data);
}).catch((t) => {
  console.log(t);
}));
```

I know this is not Scala, but I wanted to include it for completeness.
This is a mapping of `Future` to `Promise` taken from [Scala.js](https://www.scala-js.org/doc/sjs-for-js/es6-to-scala-part3.html#Futures) docs:

```
+-----------------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|              Future               |        Promise         |                                                 Notes                                                 |
+-----------------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| foreach(func)                     | then(func)             | Executes func for its side-effects when the future completes.                                         |
| map(func)                         | then(func)             | The result of func is wrapped in a new future.                                                        |
| flatMap(func)                     | then(func)             | func must return a future.                                                                            |
| recover(func)                     | catch(func)            | Handles an error. The result of func is wrapped in a new future.                                      |
| recoverWith(func)                 | catch(func)            | Handles an error. func must return a future.                                                          |
| filter(predicate)                 | N/A                    | Creates a new future by filtering the value of the current future with a predicate.                   |
| zip(that)                         | N/A                    | Zips the values of this and that future, and creates a new future holding the tuple of their results. |
| Future.successful(value)          | Promise.resolve(value) | Returns a successful future containing value                                                          |
| Future.failed(exception)          | Promise.reject(value)  | Returns a failed future containing exception                                                          |
| Future.sequence(iterable)         | Promise.all(iterable)  | Returns a future that completes when all of the futures in the iterable argument have been completed. |
| Future.firstCompletedOf(iterable) | Promise.race(iterable) | Returns a future that completes as soon as one of the futures in the iterable completes.              |
+-----------------------------------+------------------------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```